# Aggregation and filtering through the consumer template

Tags: apache-camel, aggregate, consumer

This is more a general, whats the best practice question...

I have a few processes where the consumer template has been used to read a directory (or a MQ queue) for whatever is available and then stop itself, the entire route-set it calls is created programmatically based of a few parameters

So using the consumer template method below...  Is there a way to assign

- A filter operation programmatically (ie, if i want to filter out certain files from the below, its easy if its through a standard route... (through .filter) but at the moment, i have no predefined beans, so adding #filter=filter to the EIP is not really an option).
- An aggregation function from inside my while loop.  (while still using the template).

  ```
  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

      getConsumer().start();                      
      int exchangeCount = 0;
      while (true) {
          String consumerEp = "file:d://directory?delete=true&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&idempotent=false";
          Exchange fileExchange = getConsumer().receive(consumerEp);
          if (fileExchange == null || fileExchange.getIn()==null || fileExchange.getIn().getHeader(CAMEL_FILE_NAME)==null) {
              break;
          }
          exchangeCount++;
          Boolean batchStatus = (Boolean) fileExchange.getProperty(PROP_CAMEL_BATCH_COMPLETE);
          LOG.info("---PROCESSING : " + fileExchange.getIn().getHeader(CAMEL_FILE_NAME));
          getProducer().send("direct:some-other-process", fileExchange);

          //Get the CamelBatchComplete Property to establish the end of the batch, and not cycle through twice.
          if(batchStatus!=null && batchStatus==true){
              break;                      
          }                   
      }       
      // Stop the consumer service
      getConsumer().stop();
      LOG.info("End Group Operation : Total Exchanges=" + exchangeCount);
  }
  ```